# Input layer in Processing Python script doesn't work in Model when input is a processing output

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

My processing script works fine from the scripts menu and also from a model if the input is on disk or in memory. However, if it's part of a model and uses an Algorithm output, it can't find the data source

[image]

The error is

```
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT: 'memory://MultiPolygon?crs=EPSG:28355&field=OBJECTID:integer(0,0)&field=LOT:string(5,0)&field=PLAN:string(10,0)&field=LOTPLAN:string(15,0)&field=SEG_NUM:integer(0,0)&field=PAR_NUM:integer(0,0)&field=SEGPAR:integer(0,0)&field=PAR_IND:integer(0,0)&field=LOT_AREA:double(0,0)&field=EXCL_AREA:double(0,0)&field=LOT_VOLUME:double(0,0)&field=SURV_IND:string(1,0)&field=TENURE:string(40,0)&field=PRC:integer(0,0)&field=PARISH:string(20,0)&field=COUNTY:string(16,0)&field=LAC:integer(0,0)&field=SHIRE_NAME:string(40,0)&field=FEAT_NAME:string(60,0)&field=ALIAS_NAME:string(254,0)&field=LOC:integer(0,0)&field=LOCALITY:string(30,0)&field=PARCEL_TYP:string(24,0)&field=COVER_TYP:string(10,0)&field=ACC_CODE:string(40,0)&field=CA_AREA_SQM:double(0,0)&field=O_SHAPE_AREA:double(0,0)&field=O_SHAPE_LEN:double(0,0)&field=Shape_Length:double(0,0)&field=Shape_Area:double(0,0)&field=OBJECTID_2:string(0,0)&field=LOTPLAN_2:string(0,0)&field=BUP_LOT:string(0,0)&field=BUP_PLAN:string(0,0)&field=BUP_LOTPLAN:string(0,0)&field=LOT_AREA_AM:string(0,0)&uid={b0e54775-764d-415f-a701-e3cfdb95e12d}', In_Attrib: 'LOTPLAN', OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/support.mapping1/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BMkWiy/6e8f8a6eaddc41739e79b18699fa4f7e/OUTPUT.gpkg', Out_Attrib: 'LOTPLAN', OutputS: "'SPSP'", RegexS: 'SP' }
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\processing\algfactory.py", line 276, in processAlgorithm
output = self._func(self, parameters, context, feedback, values)
File "C:\Users\support.mapping1\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\testing\processing\scripts\Search_Update.py", line 36, in searchupdatealg
layerf = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName(in_layer.sourceName())[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Error encountered while running Search and update (alg)
Execution failed after 1.99 seconds
```

**How do I define the input and how do I return the updated data as an output since it's updating the existing file?**

The processing script code is

```
from qgis import processing
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import QgsProject
import operator,re

@alg(name='searchupdatealg', label='Search and update (alg)',
     group='mgm', group_label='Custom Scripts')
# 'INPUT' is the recommended name for the main input parameter
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name='INPUT', label='Input vector')
@alg.input(type=alg.FIELD, name='In_Attrib', label='Attribute to search',
           parentLayerParameterName='INPUT')
@alg.input(type=alg.STRING, name='RegexS', label='Regex String')
@alg.input(type=alg.FIELD, name='Out_Attrib', label='Attribute to change',
           parentLayerParameterName='INPUT')
@alg.input(type=alg.EXPRESSION, name='OutputS', label='Output expression')
# 'OUTPUT' is the recommended name for the main output parameter
@alg.input(type=alg.VECTOR_LAYER_DEST, name='OUTPUT',
           label='Vector output')
           

def searchupdatealg(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """
    Search using Regex and output an expression based value
    Use standard regex to find the text to replace (it will replace all occurances as per the regex)
    Use feat['ColumnName'] in the output expression to get a value from the field.
    """
    in_layer = instance.parameterAsSource(parameters, 'INPUT', context)
    regex_s = instance.parameterAsString(parameters,'RegexS', context)
    numfeatures = in_layer.featureCount()
    feats = [f for f in in_layer.getFeatures()]
    in_attrib = instance.parameterAsString(parameters,'In_Attrib', context)
    out_attrib = instance.parameterAsString(parameters,'Out_Attrib', context)
    out_val = instance.parameterAsExpression(parameters,'OutputS', context)
    print (in_layer)
    layerf = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName(in_layer.sourceName())[0]
    i=0
    print (layerf)
    layerf.startEditing()
    for feat in feats:
        in_val = feat[in_attrib]
        if in_val!='NULL':
            if len(re.findall(regex_s, in_val))>0:
                UpdateRecord(layerf,feat,out_attrib,in_val,out_val)
                i+=1
    layerf.commitChanges()
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}
    return {'NUMBEROFFEATURES': numfeatures, 'Number changed': i}
    
def UpdateRecord(layerf,feat,out_attrib,in_val,out_val):
    out_attrib_index = feat.fields().indexFromName(out_attrib)
    print(feat.id(),out_attrib_index,in_val,str(eval(out_val))) #testing only. Comment out in production
    layerf.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), out_attrib_index, str(eval(out_val)))
```

I have also tried `alg.VECTOR_LAYER` for the input.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to get the layer from `QgsProject` since you already have the source of the input layer as an input of the processing algorithm, use:

```python
if os.path.isfile(parameters["INPUT"]):
    layerf = QgsVectorLayer(parameters["INPUT"], "Input layer", "ogr") # Shapefile/GeoPackage/... layer
else:
    layerf = context.getMapLayer(parameters["INPUT"])  # Memory layer
```

PS: `context.getMapLayer(parameters["INPUT"])` probably works for all sources I haven't used it in a while so I am not positive

To export your results to the output layer you can do the following:

```python
results = {}
(sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
    parameters,
    "OUTPUT",
    context,
    layerf.fields(),
    layerf.wkbType(),
    layerf.sourceCrs()
)
if sink is None:
    raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSinkError(parameters, "OUTPUT"))
features = layer_sites.getFeatures()
for current, feature in enumerate(features):
    # Stop the algorithm if cancel button has been clicked
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        break

    # Create a copy of the feature and
    # do some operations on the feature

    # Add a feature in the sink
    sink.addFeature(feature, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

results["OUTPUT"] = dest_id
return results
```

PS2 : If you have multiple questions try to ask them in seperate questions.

Comment: thanks - and how would I set this as an output if I don't want it to alter the input table?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: thanks but where is this placed in the code? Currently, it updates the input dataset in place, I want to be able to have the choice of either updating the input data or updating a copy of it in memory and then saving that data output.